# How can I efficiently sample a long time span in Splunk?

Tags: performance, search, time, random, splunk

I would like to run a Splunk query over a long period of time (e.g., months or years), but I am searching enough data that I am only able to search over hours or days of data.

However, for the question I want to answer in Splunk, I would be satisfied with a uniform or statistically unbiased *sample* of data. In other words, I would prefer the query return *N* events spread out over the past month, than any *N* consecutive events.

One way I considered was to only search events with `date_minute=0` so as to quickly filter 1/60th of the events, which helps but is not very flexible.

Is there a better way to sample events efficiently in Splunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a related discussion on sampling on the Splunk Answers page below.

http://answers.splunk.com/answers/3743/is-it-possible-to-get-a-sample-set-of-search-results-rather-than-the-full-search-results

An alternative to filtering by `date_minute` or `date_second`, is to filter events in a `where` clause using the `_serial` property or the `random()` function. For example,

```
* | where (_serial % 60) = 0 | ...
```

or

```
* | where (random() % 60) = 0 | ...
```

However, in both cases the search appears to do a full scan of the data. This may still be desirable if you need the flexibility and the result is feeding into a more expensive query. Otherwise, using the `date_second` approach is significantly faster because events are apparently indexed by that field. For example, the two queries above ran in `3m 20s` on a subset of data, where the query below ran in `11s` on the same data.

```
* date_second=0 | ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run a search and you are not satisfied with the performance of Splunk, then I would suggest you either [report accelerate](http://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon%3aReportacceleration) it or [data model accelerate it](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0.2/Knowledge/Acceleratedatamodels). Or you can create your own tsidx files (created automatically by report and data model acceleration) with [`tscollect`](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/tscollect), then run [`tstats`](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0.2/SearchReference/Tstats) over it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about `tscollect` and `tstats`. These look helpful. I was asking about sampling because I only need to run the query once, and my understanding is that the cost of creating the index is roughly equivalent to running the query. (Though please correct me if I'm wrong!) It could also be that the answer is there is no efficient way to sample in Splunk, and you're always better off building an index.

Answer (score 0):

Splunk now supports data sampling [link to docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.0/Search/Retrieveasamplesetofevents)